# I cannot show my output JSON file from server in an HTML page

Tags: html, node.js, express, mongoose, axios

Here's my server side code snippet (backend):

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { quotemodel } = require('./model/user')
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/qouteDB', { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
let app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyparser.json());
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './public/quotes/qoutes.html'))
})
app.post('/post', (req, res) => {
    let newQoute = new quotemodel();
    newQoute.title = req.body.title;
    newQoute.author = req.body.author;
    newQoute.body = req.body.body;

    newQoute.save(function(err, savedObject) {
        if (savedObject) { res.redirect('/viewquotes/' + req.body.author) } else { res.send(err) }
    })
})
app.get('/viewquotes/:author', (req, res) => {
    console.log('Salam');

    quotemodel.findOne({ author: req.params.author }).then((quotemodel) => {
        if (!quotemodel) {
            res.send().json({
                Error: 'Something Went Wornd' + err
            })
        }

        let data = ({
            title: quotemodel.title,
            author: quotemodel.author,
            date: quotemodel.createdAt,
            body: quotemodel.body
        })
        res.send(data)
        console.log(data);
    })
})
```

When I run the server and get to `localhost:3001/` my HTML page is loading on the port. I can enter my data and I use the (author) item form inserting in url. Next, I use the (author) as param I can access to MongoDB database and I can get my specific data and send it as JSON.

## My question

I want the following points:

1. When redirect to (/viewquotes/:author) my second page(OutPut) open
2. and when the second page is opened my JSON data rendered into Form

Here is my model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const PersianDate = require('persian-date');
PersianDate.toLocale('en')
let DateAt = new PersianDate().format('YYYY/MMMM/DD')


var qouteschema = mongoose.Schema({
    author: String,
    body: String,
    title: String,
    createdAt: { type: String, default: DateAt }
})
let quotemodel = mongoose.model('quotemodel', qouteschema);

module.exports = {
    quotemodel
}
```

this is my HTML Form For Input

```
<form action="/post" method="POST">
        <input id="title" name="title" type="text">
        <input id="body" name="body" type="text">
        <input id="author" name="author" type="text">
        <input id="send" value="send" type="submit">
    </form>
```

This my HTML Form for OutPut

```
<body>
 <div>
        <input type="text" name="author" id="author">
        <input type="text" name="body" id="body">
        <input type="text" name="title" id="title">
        <input type="date" name="time" id="time">
        <input type="button" onclick="NewIncom()">
    </div>
    <div class="viewquotes"></div>
</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="../viewqoutes.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function NewIncom() {

        axios.get('http://http://localhost:3001/viewquotes')
            .then(function(response) {
                // handle success
                document.getElementById("author").value = response.data.author;
                document.getElementById("body").value = response.data.body;
                document.getElementById("title").value = response.data.title;
                document.getElementById("time").value = response.data.date;
            })
    }
</script>
```

Comment: It is not clear what the problem is. Are you submitting the form to `/post` via `axios` too? In the second html snippet, your are issuing a `GET /viewquotes` but you don't have a route for that path defined express?

Comment: No, i am not send the form with axios.pls see the code and run , i declare path for all

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a templating engine for your html pages. Then you could use the data you send with the response to populate fields.

EJS is really easy to use. https://github.com/tj/ejs

Then you could do something like:

```html
<% if (quote) { %>
   <form action="/post" method="POST">
        <input id="title" name="title" type="text" value="<% quote.title %>">
        <input id="body" name="body" type="text" value="<% quote.body %>">
        <input id="author" name="author" type="text" value="<% quote.author %>">
        <input id="send" value="send" type="submit">
    </form>
<% } %>
```

Comment: look at the code 
i can send to backend
and i can recive from back
but i cant show my Json File in my output HTML Form
please run the server with my code